# AsynchronousClient for TCP connections. Better way for create massive clients?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, client

I'm using AsynchronousClient (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx) class for create TCP connections (clients) . I have tested just creating a few objects of that class and works ok (seems ok) but I don't know if it's the best way for create massive TCP connections. Perhaps I must use ConcurrentBag ?. Is there a better way?. Thanks

Comment: What's a "massive TCP connection"? If you mean "massive number of TCP connections", why do you need them? Why do you think `ConcurrentBag` would help you?

Comment: Yes, I meant "massive number of TCP connections". I need to be able for upload configuration to a high number of iP devices.I have seen some sample code using ConcurrentBag and Parallel.For creating many pings in parallel and works very well. I would like to know which is the best way to follow, async objects as is or ConcurrentBag &Parallel.For. Thanks